# How to make four viewport based boxes with flexbox?

Tags: html, css, sass, flexbox

I want to make four view port width and height based and not equal boxes in pure CSS.

Width must be more big than height and want it responsive

like this:

[image]

I do this:

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  padding: 25px;
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100vh - 100px);
  position: relative;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  -ms-flex-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.container.four {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.box {
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}
.box--four {
  width: 47%;
  height: 45%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container four">

    <div class="box box--four">

    </div>


    <div class="box box--four">

    </div>

    <div class="box box--four">

    </div>


    <div class="box box--four">

  </div>
</div>
```

Can i do this with pure css? or i need js for this?

Answer (score 2):

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.box {
  width: 40vw;
  height: 20vw;
  margin: 5px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

### [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lkp0p066/3/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use viewport units to make the height and width relative to the viewport height and width, then just use margins to create consistent gutters between the elements in the grid.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 1em 0 0 1em;
  background: black;
  margin: auto;
}
.box {
  width: calc(50% - 1em); height: calc(50vh - 1.5em);
  background: #171717;
  margin: 0 1em 1em 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="container four">
  <div class="box box--four">
  </div>
  <div class="box box--four">
  </div>
  <div class="box box--four">
  </div>
  <div class="box box--four">
  </div>
</div>
```